# Short Random Unique alphanumeric keys similar to Youtube IDs, in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a way to create random unique IDs similar to the YouTube IDs in Swift?

I know there are similar answers on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990820/how-can-i-make-short-random-unique-keys-like-youtube-video-ids-in-php), but they are for Php. But I want something in Swift.

I have tried using timestamp and UUIDs, but I want an alphanumeric short keys which would be around 4-10 characters so users can easily share with others verbally.

Thanks.

Comment: What is it you want to generate keys for?

Comment: For future searchers, the [hashids](http://hashids.org/swift/) library now has a version for Swift. It does just what you want - generate short, unique, non-sequential ids from integers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Looking for just a unique string

You can use [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/)s they're pretty cool:

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
print(uuid)
```

From the [ docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/)

> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally
>   Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit
>   values. UUIDs created by NSUUID conform to RFC 4122 version 4 and are
>   created with random bytes.

Some info about [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

#### Looking for a more specific length

Try something like this:

```
func randomStringWithLength(len: Int) -> NSString {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

    let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

    for _ in 1...len{
        let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.character(at: Int(rand)))
    }

    return randomString
}
```

But i'll keep my answer incase someone else stumbles upon this looking for a UUID

Comment: As right as you are, I actually need a short ID as mentioned. Like the YouTube IDs, or the tiny URLs. Around 4-10 characters which users can easily share with others verbally.

Comment: You are a life saver. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Will the random string be unique every single time? 

Comment: @Nagra no, there is no guarantee that they will be unique. You can use a UUID if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 12):

This will allow you to create a random short code. It can create codes from Hexadecimal all the way to base 62 codes and of varying lengths.

aka.

```
let myCode = ShortCodeGenerator.getCode(length: 6)
```

3dH7t8,
fdE7j1,
Gl6jKd,
Hv8gU3,

```
let myBase32Code = ShortCodeGenerator.getCode(withBase: UInt32(32), length: 6)
```

3HF75J,
J67N9D,
B47SO3,
L9SD2N

You would have to check for redundancy and then create a new one if it has already been used.

```
struct ShortCodeGenerator {

    private static let base62chars = [Character]("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)
    private static let maxBase : UInt32 = 62

    static func getCode(withBase base: UInt32 = maxBase, length: Int) -> String {
        var code = ""
        for _ in 0..<length {
            let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(min(base, maxBase)))
            code.append(base62chars[random])
        }
        return code
    }
}
```

This answer was useful in creating the above code and also has good 
[information on the number of unique identifiers you can have with each base number and length.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543715/generating-human-readable-usable-short-but-unique-ids)

The total number of unique identifiers you need can be calculated by the equation:

BaseNumber^length = # of unique IDs

EDIT:

[I have added even more functionality for converting Int's and NSDate's to shortcodes for my own project as well and put those into a project on GitHub.](https://github.com/rchatham/ShortCodeGenerator/tree/master)

Comment: How many combinations is this? Is it more random than NSUUID().UUIDString?

Answer (score 5):

> Updated for swift 3:

If you want to generate Short Random Unique alphanumeric keys, used below lines of codes;

//function defination:

```
func generateTransactionId(length: Int) -> String {
    var result = ""
    let base62chars = [Character]("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)
    let maxBase : UInt32 = 62
    let minBase : UInt16 = 32

    for _ in 0..<length {
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(min(minBase, UInt16(maxBase)))))
        result.append(base62chars[random])
    }
    return result
}
```

//function call:

```
let mTranactionId = self.generateTransactionId(length: 5) // you can change the value of length as you want
print("mTranactionId: \(mTranactionId)")
```

**Ex: Result looks like:  XHA7K, QTC92, MS1PT, YE2PV**

//Enjoy coding...!

Answer (score 3):

Does `NSUUID().UUIDString` do what you need?

Comment: As right as you are, I actually need a short ID as mentioned. Like the YouTube IDs, or the tiny URLs. Around 4-10 characters which users can easily share with others verbally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very pleased with NanoID.

https://github.com/ai/nanoid

...and here's the SWIFT version:

https://github.com/antiflasher/NanoID

You just need to drag 1 file (NanoID.swift) into your project, and you are good to go!

TAGS: Short GUID, Short UUID, Short Unique ID, Swift, iOS

Answer (score 0):

Swift custom alternative(these version doesn't check for duplicate char):

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let letters = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
    var randomString: String = ""
    for _ in 0..<length {
        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0..<letters.count)
        randomString.append(letters[randomNumber])
    }
    return randomString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this just using `UUID`.

If you don't want the whole string, as any `String` in Swift, you select a small portion of the string by using range, like this:

```swift
let text = UUID().uuidString
let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 8)
let small = text[text.startIndex..<index]
```

Notice `8` is the length of string I suggested, you can improve this by clamping this value using `min(size, text.count)` for example.

And finally, `small` is a `Substring`, to cast it to `String` just cast as usual - `String(small)`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version using a String extension

```swift
extension String {
    static func random(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

        return String((0..<length).compactMap { _ in 
            letters.randomElement()
        })
    }
}
```